# When can I use floating-point types in Java to do monetary calculations?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, cpu-architecture

I learned I cannot use floating-point types (`float`/`double` in Java) to do money calculations (and any other calculations when I need precise results). I have to use `decimal` number types (`BigDecimal` in Java) instead.

Now I wounder when I *can* use the floating-point types. Do they provide any precision guarantee ? Suppose I would like to calculate some formula with precision `0.001`. How do I know if I can use floating-point types for this calculation or not?

Comment: You can use assert statements to check the precision by subtracting a calculated value from an exact value.  But that will really only help while testing.

Comment: You just need to study [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) to know how to use floating-point numbers effectively.

Comment: Not even `0.1` is precisely representable as a floating point number. You can use them when the rounding errors that are possible as a result of the calculations you're doing are acceptable. (Unfortunately, "acceptable" is specific to what you're trying to achieve, and the possible errors have to be determined with rather ugly math.)

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/search?q=monetary+calculations+java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use floating-point types in Java, or other languages, when you can demonstrate the results are acceptable for your application.

Using BigDecimal does not solve this problem, by itself. For example, suppose a bank account contains $87.34, and you must add interest for one month given an annual percentage rate of 2.37%. First, BigDecimal will not calculate the monthly interest rate correctly, because you must divide 2.37% by 12, and 2.37/12 (or .0237/12) is not exactly representable in decimal. Second, even if BigDecimal did calculate the monthly interest rate correctly, and calculated the interest on $87.34 correctly, you probably still need to round that amount to some number of cents before adding it to the balance. The rules for that rounding may be specified in some legal document and might not match how BigDecimal does rounding.

Both decimal floating-point and binary floating-point are capable of calculating many results precisely, much more precisely than the .001 precision you suggest in your example. Both are also capable of producing significant errors when used in various ways.

Therefore, to use floating-point, you must understand what values the types can represent, what errors occur in floating-point operations, what operations you will perform, and what your application requires. Often, it is possible to avoid floating-point errors by crafting operations carefully. For example, you can work with currencies by scaling amounts to integer values (use 8734 to represent $87.34 instead of using 87.34 to represent 87.34). As another example, you can demonstrate that the accumulated error from several operations is less than half a cent, and therefore you can perform the operations and round the final result to the nearest cent, and that will be correct because the error was never large enough to make the final answer incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

> I learned I cannot use floating-point types (float/double in Java) to do money calculations

You can't use `double` to represent money over $70 trillion accurately. For values less than this you can use `double` or `long` without error (provided you use appropriate rounding)

IMHO using `double` is simpler to work with once you understand the need for rounding.

However many feel its error prone esp as you don't know who might need to maintain the code.  Using BigDecimal will ensure you use rounding correctly and give you a number of options as to how it works.

What many find disturbing is that even `0.1` is not represent precisely and BigDecimal can show the exact representation (and why you have to careful how you convert to BigDecimal)

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

prints

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Many ineffeciently use

```
new BigDecimal(Double.toString(0.1))
```

or the like which works, but ironically is only as accurate as the toString method they are trying to avoid using.

A more efficient way to do this is

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1)
```

which avoids the need to create a String.

The libraries which support `double` will display this number correctly but as soon as you perform calculation the default round may be not enough.

```
System.out.println(0.1 * 3);
```

prints

```
0.30000000000000004
```

In this situation you have to say what precision you expect. Say you have dollar and cents you can use

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", 0.1 * 3); // round output to two decimal places
```

prints

```
0.30
```

---

To find where you can not longer keep adding 0.01

```
for (double d = 1; d < Long.MAX_VALUE; d *= 2) {
    long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    double d1 = Double.longBitsToDouble(l + 1);
    if (d1 - d > 0.01) {
        System.out.println("Cannot represent " + d + " plus 0.01");
        double d_1 = Double.longBitsToDouble(l - 1);
        if (d - d_1 < 0.01)
            System.out.println("Can represent " + d + " minus 0.01");
        break;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Cannot represent 7.0368744177664E13 plus 0.01
Can represent 7.0368744177664E13 minus 0.01
```

Comment: Nitpick:  did you mean $90 trillion rather than $70 trillion?

Comment: long can represent $90 tn, but double is limited to $70 tn.

Comment: Can you explain how you got that number?  I was assuming that you were thinking of using the Double to store an integer number of cents.  In which case, a standard IEEE 754 double precision float can represent every integer in the range `[-2**53, 2**53]`, and `2**53` is just a touch larger than 9e15.  9e15 cents would be $90 trillion dollars.  But perhaps you have a different method of representation in mind?

Comment: @MarkDickinson The problem is that 2^46 - 0.01 can be represented but 2^46 + 0.01 cannot. See my example at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I would like to calculate some formula with precision 0.001. How do I know if I can use floating-point types for this calculation or not?

Floating point types are base-2, not base-10.  1/(10^n) can not be represented exactly in a (binary) floating point number, much like 1/3 can not be represented exactly in decimal number.  Floating point numbers are useful for scientific type calculations where the values may be large or small and the uncertainty of the measurements dwarfs the precision limits of the computer.  Floating point operations are quite fast, on hardware that supports it, whereas other non-integer types are not as fast.

Floating point numbers are so-called because the number of digits on each side of the fractional point will vary depending on the number.  Floating point numbers are, essentially, represented as `+/- 1.a * 2^b` where `a` and `b` are base-2 numbers.  This is akin to the decimal-based [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) `1.a * 10^b`.  See the Wikipedia article for further information on [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point.

Answer (score 1):

This video just surfaced about this topic:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

It is an excellent and easy to understand description of the "problem" with floating point operations.  They also mention the issue with monetary calculations with floating point numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Floating point types are hardware dependent, so there is no general precision guarantee. You can use them when the result does not need to be "perfect".

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug

From wikipedia: ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point )

~7.2 decimals for float

~15.9 deciamls for double

This means that it does not matter where the period is there will always be a limited number of precise digits in a number.

Comment: Java floating-point is not hardware dependent. The Java specification specifies IEEE 754 double-precision.